# How to make one button default radio button when html code does not contain options directly

Tags: html, asp.net, radio-button

How to make one button default radio button when html code does not contain options directly, data coming directly from server.

In my project I have one radio button field "Applies To".

The radio button options are not mentioned in the code as you see, I should make one option select by default, if options are not directly mentioned in the code.

How can I make one button default in this case?

```
<div class="row row-margin">
  <label style="margin-top: 34em;margin-left: -1em;">Applies To:</label>
  <label class="input" *ngFor="let question of QuestionnaireAppliesTo">
    <label class="radio">
      <span class="tableCellDisplay customRadioInline">
        <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="questionnaire.EntityTypeUniqueID" 
name="AppliesTo" class="radio-custom" [value]="question.UUID" id="type_{{question.UUID}}">
        <label for="type_{{question.UUID}}" class="radio-custom-label">{{question.Name}}</label>
      </span>
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
```

My typescript code:

```
getQuestionnaireCategories() {
  this.lookupValues.then((response: any) => {
    this.QuestionnaireAppliesTo = response.QUESTIONNAIRECATEGORIES;
  });
};
```

Comment: Please elaborate  - your question is not clear. I tried to make a proper title but I am not sure what you mean. Also you have nested labels. That cannot be correct syntax

Comment: in my project i have one radio button field "Applies To" , the radio button options are not mentioned in the code as u see , i should make one option select by default, if options are not directly mentioned in the code how can i make one button default, is there any way to make one button default

Comment: i am new to development so asking you, can we display radio button options in UI , without mentioning in code....?